# Animation "Offset" in Unity 2D animation

Tags: unity, c#, 2d, animation

I was playing around with Unity and its 2D Animator. When I press a Button now (to play for example the walk left Animation) it takes about 1 sec to begin the animation and same when I release the button to stop it. It's the same problem with every other animation.

Here's my Player Movement Controller:

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;

public class Player_Movement : MonoBehaviour {

public float speed = 10;
float old_pos;
float old_height;

void Start()
{
    old_pos = transform.position.x;
    old_height = transform.position.y;
}

void FixedUpdate()
{

    float h = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
    float v = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");


    Vector2 dir = new Vector2(h, v);
    GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = dir.normalized * speed;

    GetComponent<Animator>().SetBool("isWalkingLeft", (h < 0));

    GetComponent<Animator>().SetBool("isWalkingRight", (h > 0));
  }
}
```

The problem also occurs when I switch directions and the animation should instantly switch over.

Comment: Can you show us a screenshot of your animator controller graph, and the animation state configuration parameters for one of your walk animations? It sounds like the animation has been set to play to completion before considering a transition to a different state.

Comment: Sure, will do that when I'm Back home again!

Answer (score 1):

The default setting for a animation transition in unity, is to blend the animation sheets.  In 2D, for most cases, this is not what you want.[image]

From the sounds of it, you do not want to have a transition period between the two animations.  What you will want to do is set your transition duration to 0, and remove the check from "Has Exit Time".